# Angular2 component not rendering, neither works typing manually the link, always going to parent path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I've just started my Angular 2 journey. I’m making a small client management app to see and add clients. I was able to get working three other components but got stuck with a new one.

The components I have working so far are:

“Client”  with only a template router-outlet for the Client routes.

“ClientList” component, that renders a list of clients on the left side of the view. When a client from the list is selected, the router navigates to the client ID page/client/id. This template also has a button “Add Client” to start adding a new client.

“ClientDetail” component with a template for the client details to render the selected client details on the right side of the view.

I’m getting stuck with a “ClientNew” component. What I'd like to do is that after "Add Client" is clicked, the right side of the view is loaded with a blank form so that users can add details of a client. But whenever I click the "Add Client" it always takes me to the parent path like if page/client/new doesn't exist.

This is what I have:

**Client.routing Component**

```ts
import { NgModule }                from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }    from '@angular/router';
import { ClientsComponent }        from './clients.component';
import { ClientListComponent}      from './client-list.component';
import { ClientDetailComponent }   from './client-detail.component'; 
import { ClientDetailResolver }    from './client-detail-resolver.service';
import { ClientNewComponent   }    from './client-new.component';

 const clientRoutes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: ClientsComponent,
     children: [
       {
         path: '',
         component: ClientListComponent,
         children: [
           {
            path: ':id',
            component: ClientDetailComponent,
            resolve: {
              client: ClientDetailResolver
            }
          },
           {
             path: 'new',
             component: ClientNewComponent,
           }
        ]
      },
    ]
   }
];

@NgModule({
   imports:   [RouterModule.forChild(clientRoutes)],
   exports:   [RouterModule],
   providers: [ ClientDetailResolver]
})
export class ClientRouting { }
```

**ClientList Component**

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }     from '@angular/core';
import { Client }                from './client';
import { ClientService }         from './client.service';
import { Observable }            from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
styles: [],
  template: require('./client-list.component.html')
})

export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {
  clients: Observable<Client[]>;
  selectedId: number;

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private clientService: ClientService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.clients = this.route.params
         .switchMap((params: Params) => {
         this.selectedId = +params['id'];
         return this.clientService.getClients();
       });
  }

onSelect(client:Client): void {
  this.selectedId = client.id;
  this.router.navigate([client.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
onSelectNew(): void {
    console.log(this.router);
    this.router.navigate(['new'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    console.log('test');
}
}
```

**ClientNew Component**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Client }         from './client';
@Component({
  selector: 'new',
  templateUrl: './client-new.component.html',
  styles: []
})

export class ClientNewComponent {
  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   console.log("Test");
  }
}
```

**Clients.module**

```ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgaModule }     from '../../theme/nga.module';

import { ClientRouting } from './clients.routing';

import { ClientDetailComponent }  from './client-detail.component';
import { ClientsComponent }       from './clients.component';
import { ClientService }          from './client.service';
import { ClientListComponent }    from './client-list.component';
import { ClientNewComponent }    from './client-new.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:     [CommonModule,FormsModule,NgaModule,ClientRouting],
  declarations: [ClientsComponent, ClientDetailComponent,ClientHomeComponent, ClientListComponent, ClientNewComponent],
  providers:[ClientService]
})
export default class ClientsModule {}
```

Comment: So, after a little more digging I got it working but I do not understand it yet. What I did was to move the path: 'new' above path: ':id', it is still a child of ClientListComponent, having the path:'new' on top of ":id" got it working. Anyone can explain how why?

Comment: And after more research I find out that order matters in routing. When the router receives an url, it will go through the configuration in order: from the first element of the configuration array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And after more research I find out that order matters in routing.  http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/